# mypy - using a python float for numpy double fails validation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mypy

Why does the code below fail Mypy validation?

```py
import numpy as np

def f(v: np.double) -> None: pass

f(0.0)                # error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "float"; expected "floating[_64Bit]"
```

explicit conversion does work, but quite cumbersome to the caller and makes the code harder to read:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(v: np.double) -> None: pass

f(np.double(0.0))
```

Alternatively, I could change the signature of the function, and do the conversion in the body:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(v: np.double | float) -> None: _ = np.double(v)

f(0.0)
```

As I am trying to write an API, the latter is probably the most user friendly.

But is there a better way of solving this?